Azure Devops Pipelines: Iterate steps over variable
Can I dynamically iterate steps over a set variable with Azure Devops pipelines?
In the below pipeline I split the comma-separated-string into multiple job steps:
variables:
  - name: fruitList
    value: mango,peach

stages:
    - stage: Dev
      dependsOn: []
      jobs:
        - job: Setup
          steps:
            - task: AzureCLI@2
              name: SetVariable
              displayName: SetVariable
              inputs:
                scriptType: bash
                scriptLocation: inlineScript
                inlineScript: |
                  set -xe
                  set -o nounset
                  # publish a list of fruits
                  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=fruitList;isOutput=true]apple,banana,orange"
        - job: CreateDynamicJobs
          dependsOn: Setup
          # variables:
          #   - name: fruitList
          #     value: $[ dependencies.Setup.outputs['InstallTerrafom.fruitList'] ]
          steps:
            - ${{ each fruitName in split(variables.fruitList, ',') }}:
                - task: AzureCLI@2
                  displayName: "Step dynamic ${{ fruitName }}"
                  inputs:
                    scriptType: bash
                    scriptLocation: inlineScript
                    inlineScript: |
                      set -xe
                      set -o nounset
                      echo "${{ fruitName }}"

The above pipeline will succeed, while echoing the initial variable values: mango and peach. BUT I want to iterate over apple banana and orange by uncommenting the set variable.
There will be one step named Step dynamic $[ dependencies.Setup.outputs['InstallTerrafom.fruitList'] ]

From your YAML sample, you are using logging command to set the variable: fruitList. The variable will be set and expand at runtime.
But the each expression will read the variable at compile time.
In this case, the each expression will read the initial variable values and not able to read the updated variable value.
I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can dynamically iterate steps over a runtime variable with Azure DevOps pipelines.
Currently, the each expression can loop the value from the Parameters or the variable set in the Variables field.
For example:
variables:
   fruitList: apple,banana,orange

For a workaround, you need to split the pipeline into two pipelines. One is used to set  and pass the variable and the other is used to get and split the value to iterate steps.
Here is an example:
Pipeline One:
stages:
- stage: Dev
  dependsOn: []
  jobs:
    - job: Setup
      steps:
      - task: AzureCLI@2
        name: SetVariable
        displayName: SetVariable
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: xx
          scriptType: bash
          scriptLocation: inlineScript
          inlineScript: |
            set -xe
            set -o nounset
            # publish a list of fruits
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=fruitList]apple,banana,orange"
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            $token = "$(pat)"      
            $url="https://dev.azure.com/{Orgname}/{Projectname}/_apis/pipelines/{PipelineRunID}/runs?api-version=5.1-preview"
            
            $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
            
            $JSON = "
            {
              
            
            
              `"resources`": {
                `"repositories`": {
                  `"self`": {
                    `"ref`": `"refs/heads/main`"
                  }
                }
              },
              `"templateParameters`": {
                `"fruitList`":`"$(fruitList)`"
              },
            
            
            
            }"
            
            
            $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json  

Pipeline Two:
parameters:
  - name: fruitList
    type: string
    default: mango,peach
stages:
- stage: Dev
  dependsOn: []
  jobs:
  - job: CreateDynamicJobs
    steps:
      - ${{ each fruitName in split(parameters.fruitList, ',') }}:
          - task: AzureCLI@2
            displayName: "Step dynamic ${{ fruitName }}"
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'xx'
              scriptType: 'bash'
              scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
              inlineScript: |
                set -xe    
                set -o nounset    
                echo "${{ fruitName }}"

Result:

I can fully understand your requirement. You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: Developer Community to report this feature

Yes this works thanks. But I think I haven't exhausted my options to make this work within a single pipeline

@JoostDöbken  Thanks for your update. I can understand your requirement. But I am afraid that single pipeline can not fully meet your requirement well. You need to hard code the Parameters value or the variable value set in the Variables field.
