USING RUNTIME VARIABLES IN AZURE YAML CHECKOUT
Azure devops pipeline
I am trying to checkout 2 repositories. The one which I’m running from is fine. The second repository. I retrieve a branch name from job 1. I then pass this branch name into the checkout of the second repository using inline commands and environmental variables. But it does not work.
Trying to dynamically change a branch during a YAML for checking out a repo. the below is an extract of the code, there are more defined variables which i have removed
code:
stages:

- stage: build
  jobs:
  - job: config
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      clean: true
      submodules: recursive
      persistCredentials: true
    - task: CmdLine@1
      inputs:
        filename: Call
        arguments: (here calling a script which sets PRJ_BRANCH, removed for Export Control)
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(OUTPUTDIR)'
        ArtifactName: Reports
      condition: succeededOrFailed()
    
- stage: projectconfig
  dependsOn:
  - build
  variables:
    prjref: $[ stageDependencies.build.config.outputs['CmdLine.PRJ_BRANCH'] ]
  jobs:
  - job: test
    steps:
    - script: echo $(prjref)
    - checkout: self
      # clean: true
      # submodules: recursive
      # persistCredentials: true
    - checkout: repo@$(prjref)


What exactly does it mean But it does not work? Anny error messages? Are you talking about Azure DevOps pipelines? Could you please edit your post and past the pipeline, or at least the relevant part?

@RuiJarimba I have updated with the code, the error seems to be the pipeline is reading the yaml variable prjref during compiling the yaml, i need this to be done during runtime so stage 1 can dynamically attach the branch name to that variable. As you can see i am then reading the variable in stage 2. it is being set correctly from a python script as an evironmental variable

Shouldn't you set the name property to CmdLine in the task that sets variable PRJ_BRANCH? What can you tell us about this variable? Is that supposed to be the branch that is currently being used by the pipeline? Can you please include the definition of repo?

@RuiJarimba REPO is the github repository i want to checkout.
PRJ Branch is the reference branch to which i want to checkout out the repository to.
The Name doesnt seem to make a difference, the Echo statement is printing the variable correctly. (The variable being the branch name)

@RuiJarimba The branch PRJREF is not the branch currently used in the build. This is where it is confusing, it is a branch name specifically obtained in the first stage, it is unique, and also exists in the other repository. I have tested by writing the exact branch and it works fine. So the issue is the variables

@user27194034 Since you are using Github Repo as repo resources, you need to use Repo resources to reference the github repo. In this case, the checkout step can not use any variables. And the repo resources ref field doesn't support runtime variable. Due to this limitations, I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can directly meet your requirement. You can refer to my answer to get more details.

Based on your comments, you are using Github Repo as the repo resource. In this case, you need to set the Repo Resource to reference the Github repo.
I am afraid that the Repo Resource doesn't support using the variables to define the branch in checkout step(e.g. - checkout: repo@$(prjref)).
We need to define the define ref settings in Repo resource to define the checkout branch.
For example:
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyGitHubRepo
    type: github
    endpoint: MyGitHubServiceConnection
    name: MyGitHubOrgOrUser/MyGitHubRepo
    ref: ${{ variables['Build.SourceBranch'] }}

steps:
- checkout: MyGitHubRepo

The ref field in Repo resource only supports compile time variable (e.g. ${{ variables['Build.SourceBranch'] }}).
Refer to this doc: resources.repositories.repository definition

ref name to checkout; defaults to 'refs/heads/main'. The branch checked out by default whenever the resource trigger fires. Template expressions are supported.

Currently, Azure DevOps only supports using runtime variables in Inline syntax checkout. But only Azure Repos Git repositories in the same organization can use the inline syntax.
For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Check out multiple repositories in your pipeline
Update:
For a workaround, we can spilt the single pipeline into two pipelines to run the two stages. One is used to set the variable and pass the value to parameters in Pipeline two. The other Pipeline use the parameters  collect the branch name and use it in the ref field.
Here is an example:
Pipeline One
stages:

- stage: build
  jobs:
  - job: config
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      clean: true
      submodules: recursive
      persistCredentials: true
    - task: CmdLine@1
      inputs:
        filename: Call
        arguments: (here calling a script which sets PRJ_BRANCH, removed for Export Control)
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(OUTPUTDIR)'
        ArtifactName: Reports
      condition: succeededOrFailed()
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
              $token = "$(pat)"      
              $url="https://dev.azure.com/{Orgname}/{Projectname}/_apis/pipelines/{PipelineRunID}/runs?api-version=5.1-preview"
              
              $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
              
              $JSON = "
              {
                
              
              
                `"resources`": {
                  `"repositories`": {
                    `"self`": {
                      `"ref`": `"refs/heads/main`"
                    }
                  }
                },
                `"templateParameters`": {
                  `"Outputref`":`"$(PRJ_BRANCH)`"
                },
              
              
              
              }"
              
              
              $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json  

Pipeline Two:
parameters:
  - name: Outputref
    type: string
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: repo
    type: github
    endpoint: MyGitHubServiceConnection
    name: MyGitHubOrgOrUser/MyGitHubRepo
    ref: ${{ parameters.Outputref }}


stages:

- stage: projectconfig
  jobs:
  - job: test
    steps:
    - script: echo ${{ parameters.Outputref }}
    - checkout: self
      # clean: true
      # submodules: recursive
      # persistCredentials: true
    - checkout: repo  

In this case, the variable value: PRJ_BRANCH will be passed from Pipeline one to Pipeline two ->  parameters. And it can be used in the ref field of the repo resources.

So ultimately, What i intend to do is not possible so i need to seek a manual way around it? The system currently only supports compile time variables? Your answer is very clear. Thanks

@user27194034 Yes. The repo resources only supports compile time variables for the time being. I can fully understand your requirement. For  a workaround to let your process work, you can consider splitting the Pipeline into two  pipelines to run the two stages. In this case, you can use the parameters in the second pipeline to collect the branch name and use it in the ref field.  You can  refer to my ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78522003/azure-devops-pipelines-iterate-steps-over-variable/78522048#78522048

@user27194034 Based on your actual situation, I have added a sample in the update of my answer. You can check it.

Great thank you!
